# Markov kernels and update functions

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, markov-chains

I would like to prove, that for any Markov kernel $K$ on a Polish space $(F,\mathcal{F})$ (with a $\sigma$-field) you can find a measurable space $(S,\mathcal{S})$, a random element $Z$ on $S$ and an update function $\alpha:F\times S\to F$ such that for $A\in\mathcal{F}$ it holds
$$K(x,A) = P(\alpha(x,Z)\in A) \qquad \mbox{for all }x\in F.
$$
Does anyone have any hints on how this can be accomplished?

If the Polish space is $\mathbb{R}$, one can take the cdf $F_y(x) = K(y,(-\infty,x])$ and define $(S,\mathcal{S})=([0,1],\mathcal{B}([0,1])$, $Z=U$ for a uniform $U$ and $\alpha(y,u):= F_y^{\leftarrow}(u)$ (the generalized inverse). This can be done for any $y\in\mathbb{R}$.
But the general case of a Polish state space?

**Edit**: In fact, finding a proof for the case where the Polish space is $\mathbb{R}^n$ would be satisfying.

Comment: Since every (sufficiently large) Polish space is Borel isomorphic to $[0,1]$, proving it for $\mathbb R$ is enough and you've done it already... Of course, I assume that $\mathcal F$ is (a subalgebra of) the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $F$. Otherwise the Polish space structure is completely useless and the statement is false as written.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, do you mind elaborating a bit?
EDIT: Yes it is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Elaborating on which part?

Comment: How I extend my result to $\mathbb{R}^n$ by making use of the fact you state (that under some conditions a Polish space is isomorphic to $[0,1]$).

Comment: Let $F:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R^n$ be a Borel isomorphism. Transfer $K$ to $\mathbb R$ putting $K'(x,A)=K(F(x),F(A))$, build $Z'$ for $K'$ and put $Z=F(Z')$.

Comment: I'm a noob with statements like this, so I will give it a try a bit later. Thank you very much!